# Parent Account -- View Hierarchy

Tags: account

[image]

As I can see the ***view hierarchy*** option beside **Account Name** field. Can I create something similar of that kind besides my **OwnerAccount** field. As my OwnerAccount will be having multiple records. If I can establish view hierarchy option it will easy to see the hierarchy. Any insights would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it by creating the field as a VisualForce page, and then including it in your layout.  Here's the page with the right styling for 2 column grids (it resizes correctly as well):

```
<apex:page standardController="Case__c" standardStylesheets="true">
<body style="margin: 0px;"> 
    <apex:form >
        <div class="bPageBlock brandSecondaryBrd bDetailBlock secondaryPalette">
            <div class="pbBody">
                <div class="pbSubsection" >
                    <table class="detailList" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" >
                        <tr>
                            <td class="labelCol" style="width:36%;">Record Type</td>
                            <td class="dataCol" style="width:64%;"><apex:outputField value="{!Case__c.RecordTypeId}" />&nbsp;<apex:outputLink target="_top" value="/apex/Case_CreationWorkFlow?Id={!Case__c.Id}&AccountName={!Case__c.Account__r.Name}&ResidentName={!Case__c.Resident__r.Name}" rendered="{!Case__c.Case_Status__c != 'Closed'}">[Change Case Type]</apex:outputLink></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </apex:form>
</body>
</apex:page>
```